# Why don't we use octogonal maps instead of hexagonal maps?

Tags: grid, level-design, hexagonal-grid

I understand the advantage of hexagonal tiles over square ones. But why aren't octagons used instead? I would think they would provide better, more natural movement in eight directions.

I was thinking about using that kind of map in some game, but I haven't seen any games using it, so I wonder if I missed something obviously flawed about using it?

Comment: Octagons don't tile.

Comment: @BorealGames It makes sense now ^^

Comment: I wonder if there are any other shapes that tile like squares and hexagons

Comment: @Azaral: There are only triangles, squares, and hexes. This has been proven.

Comment: That makes me a little sad inside

Comment: Well, actually there are tilings with other regular polygons, but only in non-euclidian geometries. You can get a regular pentagon tiling on a sphere for instance.

Comment: @Azaral Don't worry, it's only true in flat 2D. On curved surfaces, e.g. the sphere surface mentioned by TonioElGringo, other tilings are possible, see [Uniform tilings in hyperbolic plane#Regular hyperbolic tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane#Regular_hyperbolic_tilings)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Octogons:

[image]

Hexagons:

[image]

The gaps in the octogons make for an unappealing game world.

Typically, if you wanted to allow for eight directions of movement, you would just use squares.

Comment: An alternative is to have your game take place on the hyperbolic plane, where you can tile with octogons: http://www.roguetemple.com/z/hyper.php

Comment: @MartianInvader How Interesting!

Comment: "The gaps in the octogons make for an unappealing game world." I wouldn't say so, I certainly see usage for a pattern like that for less visible tiling.

Comment: True enough, "unappealing" is the wrong word. I should say, the non-uniform structure introduces additional complexity for both the end user (who might have a hard time getting used to such a structure) and for the developer, who will likely find it more challenging to code for.

Comment: The octagonal pattern with gaps is equivalent to a square pattern without diagonal movement, visually rotated 45 degrees! (And if you fill the gaps with square tiles, it's a square pattern *with* diagonal movement, but weirder)

Comment: Is there a reason why you included a link to the octagons, but a picture of the hexagons? Seems odd to me

Comment: @Ferrybig It was an image, 5 years ago. Stackexchange altered the requirements for linked images. It's been updated.

Answer (score 74):

To summarize and elaborate upon what has been said in other answers and in comments, triangles, squares and hexagons are the only mathematically possible [regular tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_tiling#Regular_tilings) aka [regular tessellations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) of the [Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_plane). So yeah, this sucks. Triangles are completely useless here, squares suck because you can't move diagonally without having a somewhat unwieldy factor of 1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480 ... give or take; and hexagons suck because you can't even move straight in both directions. Don't get me wrong, I still prefer them over squares within the constraints of the crappy reality mathematics left us with and go Civ5 for finally switching to hex grids. But still, if it *were* possible to tessellate with octagons, nobody would ever take a second look at hexagons.

You could say "Well, I don't care if there are gaps. I just pretend they aren't there." You'd get the [truncated square tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_square_tiling) which is called *square* tiling not because there are little square gaps but because those octagons are in fact just glorified squares in terms of tiling the plane. Those little squares are what's left from [truncating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_%28geometry%29) the corners off the squares that would actually tile the plane and in game terms, the reason to not use squares in the first place was to have an equal distance for straight and diagonal moves and this is what you don't have here. Diagonal moves have to bridge the same distance between tile centers as they would with square tiles. Conversely, if you pretend your magic digital space had actual holes, you can of course do that but what's the difference from just using square tiles and making diagonal moves just as expensive as straight ones?

[image: truncated square tiling]

Now this all wouldn't be so bad if there were really good alternatives that [aren't Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry). Often, our grid is on some kind of planet anyway, so why not use an elliptic geometry, i.e. the surface of a sphere? Unfortunately, spheres are even much, much worse when it comes to regular tilings. Where in the plane you can at least use as many or as little tiles as you like, on spheres there are five arrangements, the Platonic solids. That's it. And only two of them don't use triangles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polyhedra

However, the *hyperbolic* plane really rocks when it comes to tessellations. There aren't just three, in fact there's an infinite number of regular tessellations, including an [octagonal one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octagonal_tiling).

[image: octagonal tiling in the hyperbolic plane]

The only problem is that the [hyperbolic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) isn't something as nice as a flat surface or a sphere but basically the [surface of a Pringle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid#Applications). You'd need one hell of a story hook to justify a game on a Pringle ;)

[image: hyperbolic paraboloid]

Still, the octagonal tiling is so elegant and the [Poincaré disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disc_model) looks so awesome that I'm really surprised it's almost never been done (previously I said "never been done" here but then I read [MartianInvader](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/29674/martianinvader)'s comment pointing to [HyperRogue](http://www.roguetemple.com/z/hyper.php)).

Implementation-wise, while I've never done it myself, it should be fairly straightforward to implement this with today's 3D architectures, since a Poincaré disc view can be constructed by putting everything on the surface of a [hyperboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) and doing a perspective projection (see [Relation to the hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Relation_to_the_hyperboloid_model)).

[image: construction of Poincare disk]

Just one more thing to conclude this, in case you think about doing a grid-based space game and going to three dimensions, hoping that things might look rosier there ... better just give up. Not only would you need a regular convex polyhedron with 14 faces which [doesn't exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid), the only way to tessellate 3D Euclidean space with regular convex polyhedra is with cubes. Booooring. [In hyperbolic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_honeycombs_in_hyperbolic_space) you can at least get *something* vaguely like the analogon to a hex grid by tessellating with dodecahedra (i.e. 12-faced polyhedra; that's *almost* 14, right?) but now you're in total brainfuck land and still haven't got the counterpart to an octagonal tiling:

[image: Hyperbolic orthogonal dodecahedral honeycomb]

Beautiful as hell? Oh my God, yes! Would I panic beyond measure if alien spaceships came after me in this and I was expected to react in a sensible way? You bet I would. This is probably the reason why most people just use either cubes or [hexagonal prismatic stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_uniform_honeycomb#The_G.7E2xI.7E1.28.E2.88.9E.29.2C_.5B6.2C3.2C2.2C.E2.88.9E.5D_prismatic_group).

[image: cubic honeycomb]
[image: hexagonal prismatic honeycomb]

Comment: Pro tip: if you feel like being elected official ruler of the nerdiverse, make a Dwarf Fortress in a dodecahedral honeycomb in hyperbolic space. If you don't want anyone to challenge you for that title ever again and also make the Vulcans land and offer their submission under your rule before we even invent the warp drive, write it in an according Funge dialect (http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html).

Comment: 3D does have a regular analogue of the hex grid, namely the [FCC lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres), whose unit cell, the [rhombic dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedral_honeycomb), is a [Catalan solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_solid) (i.e. all its faces are identical and symmetric, even though not all the corners are). Haven't seen many games using it, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You're right, a honeycomb of Catalan solids would be acceptable, too, since the distance between adjacent cells would be equal. I didn't think of that :)

Comment: Something I also thought about but couldn't find anything on: is there maybe a way to cheat. I mean everything here was about mathematically correct answers and regular shapes and whatnot. But for a game it would be perfectly fine if you distorted everything just a tiny bit as long as the player doesn't notice. I can very well imagine that you project the octagonal tiling in hyperbolic space onto a sphere and then somehow fiddled with the lines so that everything fits together on the other end. But that would be cheating twice and I have no idea how ugly it would turn out to be.

Comment: Awesome answer, now I can't wait for a successor to Freelancer set in hyperbolic space due to some... accident.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Despite what I said in the answer, that would be pretty awesome. If a game isn't able to rewire our brains to comprehend 3D hyberbolic space, then what is? :)

Comment: @Christian Indeed :) Although [4D games](https://libregamewiki.org/4D_games) such as [Adanaxis](https://libregamewiki.org/Adanaxis) (I haven't played it yet, though) may also be an interesting alternative. Hm, I wonder whether there are sensible higher dimensional honeycombs, but then this question would drift more and more towards http://math.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Isn't the 4D Rubik's cube missing from that list? Anyway, Adanaxis sounds gleefully insane. As for higher dimensions, geometry becomes surprisingly boring in higher dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regular_polytopes#Tessellations It really boggles my mind. I would expect there to be more degrees of freedom so more polytopes and stuff. But no. Even hyperbolic space that has that infinite number of tessellations in 2D space goes down to 0 in dimensions >5. Euclidean space retains its cubic tessellation in all dimensions.

Comment: Maybe I dismissed triangles too early. This game uses an interesting triangular/hexagonal hybrid by making figures stand on the vertices and using the edges for movement and interaction: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/482445197/unsung-story-tale-of-the-guardians

Comment: +1 for "You'd need one hell of a story hook to justify a game on a Pringle."

Comment: About cheating for spheres: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Climatron,_Missouri_Botanical_Gardens.jpg (non-triangular geodesic dome) and http://www.xsi-blog.com/archives/115 plus http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/voronoi/.

Comment: And to extend on that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_grid http://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/icosahedron.html

Comment: There's a really great series of videos being created right now by the author of Hyperbolica, a game under development that's set in 3D hyperbolic space: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMKLeS-Uq_8&list=PLh9DXIT3m6N4qJK9GKQB3yk61tVe6qJvA&ab_channel=CodeParade

Answer (score 30):

The author of HyperRogue here.

HyperRogue actually uses a tesselation made of hexagons and heptagons, here is the reason why this particular tesselation has been chosen, instead of only octagons or heptagons, for example: [Hyperbolic geometry in Hyperbolic Rogue](http://zenorogue.blogspot.com/2012/03/hyperbolic-geometry-in-hyperbolic-rogue.html) Basically, the octagons are too big.

[image: Screenshot HyperRogue]
[image: Numbered Screenshot]

Also some consequences of using hyperbolic geometry in a game (what works in hyperbolic and do not work in Euclidean, and vice versa) are listed in that post.

And yes, as Christian guessed, HyperRogue internally uses the hyperboloid model.

I am not allowed to comment on Christian's answer, but there is a tesselation of the 3D space with 14-faced polyhedra: [Bitruncated Cubic Honeycomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitruncated_cubic_honeycomb) (why 14 faces, anyway?)

Comment: Damn, only now saw your post. Yeah, I overlooked the bitruncated cubic honeycomb but Ilmari Karonen was also nice enough to point me to it. Really nice work you did with HyperRogue BTW. Any chance you'll be adding Ouya controls to it? :)

Comment: I got confused again. The bitruncated cubic honeycomb is not made up of regular polyhedra, i.e. not all faces are the same. The honeycomb Ilmari Karonen mentioned is made up of dodecahedra, i.e. 12-faced solids, that's why it's sort of the analogon to the hexagonal tiling: it works but it doesn't have the 14 directions you'd want (six "straight" directions for each face of a cube and eight "diagonal" ones for each vertex). The bitruncated cubic honeycomb is the analogon to the flat octagonal tiling: it works, but it doesn't have any advantage over a cubic honeycomb for game grids.

Comment: I added a screenshot so you could understand the tiling. However, maybe it's just me but I found it really hard to even see how many vertices each tile had. So I put the numbers of vertices in each of the tiles (well, not *all* of them actually) and suddenly the pattern became clear: it's overlapping circles of hexagons with heptagons in the middle. Hope it's ok that I messed with your answer, @ZenoRogue and sorry if I'm just slow with these things and y'all got it right away.

Comment: Thanks! What does it take to add Ouya controls? There is already an Android port, and joystick controls (for the Pandora console), so Ouya controls should be easy to add, although hard for me to test.

Comment: I think we would actually require 26 directions, not 14 (6 "pure" directions, 12 combinations of two (non-opposite) pure directions, and 8 combinations of three pure directions). The bitruncated cubic honeycomb uses 6+8 (corresponding to faces and vertices), and rhombic takes the other 12 (corresponding to edges).

Comment: Take a classical football (soccer ball), made of black pentagons and hexagons. This is spherical geometry. If you replace pentagons with hexagons, this no longer loops, and you get a hex tiling of a plane. If you replace them with heptagons instead, you get a tiling of a hyperbolic plane.

Comment: I think the b.c.h. is the best 3D analogue of the hex tiling of the plane, and thus has its advantages. Consider a line of circles (A). You can add another line of circles (B) on the top of it. You could place each B-circle directly over an A-circle (and thus get a square tiling) or put each of them between two A-circles (and thus get a hex tiling). Now, take this into three dimensions: you have balls arranged in a hex tiling on a plane, and you add another layer, to make it 3D -- if you place them directly above you get a hex prism, and if not, you get the b.c.h.

Comment: @Christian The problem with rhombic, cubic, and hex prism (as well as the square tiling of the plane) is that there are tiles which only share a vertex or an edge, and it is not clear whether it should be possible to move between them or not. Hex tiling of the plane, its spherical/hyperbolical analogues, as well as the b.c.h. are better in this regard. I wonder whether the Weaire–Phelan structure would be practical for a game...

Comment: Whoa, lots of messages and it's already late here. I think can't wrap my brain around 3D tessellations anymore today. I haven't done any development for the Ouya myself but this makes it sound as if you can check for joystick input without even installing the Ouya ODK https://devs.ouya.tv/developers/docs/controllers Which would be good because apparently you need an Ouya to use the ODK? https://devs.ouya.tv/developers/docs/setup Makes no sense but that's what it says to me on first glance. You app runs just fine on the Ouya but the input using the touchpad is very tedious of course.

Comment: @ZenoRogue If you want, you can send APKs my way and I'll gladly test them. I'd also take a look at your sources myself but I'm currently a bit low on time and the last time I tried to set up an Android development environment, that Google Eclipse thingy didn't do what it was supposed to do and things got really ugly really quickly so that sucked. But if you already have joystick controls in place, that's really encouraging for the coding part itself. Anyway, I'll get some sleep now and read the rest tomorrow :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it is too hard for me to add Ouya controls without understanding Ouya (when adding Pandora joysticks, my code caused movement in weird directions -- I needed to play it on a real Pandora and see exactly what the joysticks report to fix the problem). If you want to try it yourself, that could be nice and I could help about the general structure :) (updated the Android sources on my site to 44a) It would be cooler to support any kind of Android joystick than just Ouya, but your link does use the ODK, so I am not sure whether it would work elsewhere.

Comment: The difference between a cubic tiling and a bitruncated cubic one is purely cosmetic so if it's just to make it clear to players where they can and can't move then that's fine but it doesn't really change anything mathematically. It surely doesn't have the elegance of a real 2D hexagonal tiling (it pretty much is the analog of the 2D octagonal tiling). I like your analogy to sphere packing but what you actually get is the rhombic dodecahedral honeycomb. 26 directions ... yeah, you might actually be right. I forgot the edges of the cube.

Comment: @ZenoRogue Is there such a thing as a general Android joystick API?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I am not sure, there is a generic MotionEvent which is said to report joystick events, but I cannot find details about it. I think you are right about the sphere packing, although with a bit different packing of hex grids you would get the b.c.h. I don't agree there is no difference between cubic and b.c.h., they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 9):

Basically what you want is a monohedral tesselation (or tiling), that is a coverage of the entire plane (assuming 2d) with a single shape where the tiles do neither overlap nor leave gaps.

There are lots of shapes with which this can be done but when we introduce other constraints, usually orientation should stay the same or they should conform to a natural movement direction, basically only squares and hexagons remain.

Take the triangle for examples (which you might know from the tesselation of 3d objects). To fill the gaps between two triangels another triangle has to be inserted, but flipped upside down. This is obviously a hassle to generate when dealing with sprites for example since a seamless connection is important. Also triangular movement sucks.

The most natural, with regard to movement at least, is the square which happens to be the most frequently used. Hexagons are the next best thing and allow for more direct approach to a higher number of movement directions, i.e. not over the corner movement like 8-way movement on squares does. Usually they are used in more tactical games where the increase in movement is important.

Anyway, if you want to read up more, take a look at http://euler.slu.edu/escher/index.php/Tessellations_by_Polygons.